# How to find probability of one pair poker?

Tags: probability, poker

I have the following problem:

[image]

So my main question is how am I supposed to choose the rank of the cards when trying to calculate the probability of one pair?
I don't have the usual 52 deck of cards so I don't have joker, queen and king (I assume the digit "1" is supposed to represent ace).

If it would be a 52 deck of cards it would turn out that you can choose 13 ranks, but I have a trouble of deciding how to choose the rank? Should I focus on all the matching digits with the four different colors? In that case I can only match up to the digit 7.

Some guidence would be really appreciated!

Comment: If I have interpreted your question correctly, a pair would be two cards of the same color. As we have 34 cards, the probability of a pair is, $$\frac{10}{34}\frac{9}{33}+\frac{9}{34}\frac{8}{33}+\frac{7}{34}\frac{8}{33}+\frac{7}{34}\frac{6}{33}$$ Its been a while since I have done any probability but this makes the most sense?

Comment: @OliverMurfett One pair is a hand that contains two cards of one rank and three cards of three other ranks.

Comment: Surely a pair means two cards of the same rank (both $3's$ or such).

Comment: Ah okay, well say you pick any number 1-7 as your first card, which happens $\frac{28}{34}$ times this leaves 33 cards remaining, 3 of which are the same as yours. Then for an 8, this happens $\frac{3}{34}$ times, and there are 2 out of 33 cards that will give you a pair. For 9, $\frac{2}{34}$, and only 1 other card will give you a pair. If you pick 10, you cannot pick a pair.$$\frac{28}{34}\frac{3}{33}+\frac{3}{34}\frac{2}{33}+\frac{2}{34}\frac{1}{33}$$ I apologize for my confusion, I hope this is the correct interpretation to your problem.

Comment: @OliverMurfett Well I'm trying to figure it out by these 7 matching values and colors. I'm thinking it like this. If I want one pair then I have 7 matching values to choose from (the fact that 8, 9 and 10 don't show up in the blue cards). That leaves me with 6 ranks  for the three non-matching remaining cards, and I represent it bionimal (6 3). Then I have to choose color for the pair, I have 4 colors so there should be 2 colors for the pair (4 2) and lastly I have 3 cards out of five that I choose color for (4 1) (4 1) (4 1) . So I'm thinking 7*20*6*4*4*4 = 53760 -> 53760 / 278256

Comment: where 278256 is the total (unique poker hands)

Comment: What is the source of the problem, and what was the intended solution approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach, considering 16 cases.
\begin{align}
&a,a,8,9,10, \text{ with $a\le 7$}:&& \binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1} = 252\\
&a,a,b,8,9, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7$}:&& \binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1} = 6048\\
&a,a,b,8,10, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7$}:&& \binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{1}{1} = 3024\\
&a,a,b,9,10, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7$}:&& \binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1} = 2016\\
&a,a,b,c,8, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7, c\le 7$}:&& \binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2\binom{3}{1} = 30240\\
&a,a,b,c,9, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7, c\le 7$}:&& \binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2\binom{2}{1} = 20160\\
&a,a,b,c,10, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7, c\le 7$}:&& \binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2\binom{1}{1} = 10080\\
&a,a,b,c,d, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7, c\le 7, d\le 7$}:&& \binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3 = 53760\\
&8,8,a,9,10, \text{ with $a\le 7$}:&& \binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1} = 168\\
&8,8,a,b,9, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7$}:&& \binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2\binom{2}{1} = 2016\\
&8,8,a,b,10, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7$}:&& \binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2\binom{1}{1} = 1008\\
&8,8,a,b,c, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7, c\le 7$}:&& \binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3 = 6720\\
&9,9,a,8,10, \text{ with $a\le 7$}:&& \binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{1}{1} = 84\\
&9,9,a,b,8, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7$}:&& \binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2\binom{3}{1} = 1008\\
&9,9,a,b,10, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7$}:&& \binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2\binom{1}{1} = 336\\
&9,9,a,b,c, \text{ with $a\le 7, b\le 7, c\le 7$}:&& \binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3 = 2240
\end{align}
Adding these up yields $139160$ hands. Now divide by $\binom{34}{5}=278256$ to get the probability.

---

Alternatively, you can use the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Overcount of one pair ($aa$ with $a \le 7$, $88$, $99$):
$$\binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{34-4}{3}
+\binom{3}{2}\binom{34-3}{3}
+\binom{2}{2}\binom{34-2}{3}=188965
$$

Two pairs ($aabb$ with $a \le 7$ and $b \le 7$, $aa88$, $aa99$, $8899$):
$$\binom{7}{2}\binom{4}{2}^2\binom{34-8}{1}
+\binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{34-7}{1}
+\binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\binom{34-6}{1}
+\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2}\binom{34-5}{1}=24321
$$

Full houses ($aaabb$ with $a \le 7$ and $b \le 7$, $aaa88$, $aaa99$, $88899$):
$$\binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{2}
+\binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{3}{2}
+\binom{7}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{2}{2}
+\binom{3}{3}\binom{2}{2}
=1163
$$

Pairs minus twice two-pairs minus full houses:
$$188965-2(24321)-1163=139160$$

Comment: @DonThousand np